# Calculate offset point coordinate between two points

Tags: javascript, geometry, html5-canvas

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to word this, so picture time.

I have points arranged in a circle, I know the `x,y` coordinates for all of them.

[image]

I can iterate each point and draw a line between them, easy

```
//in a for each dot loop..
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
ctx.stroke();
```

[image]

This is where I'm up to now. The rest I can't figure out

While iterating a point, I'd like to create a "diversion" that alternates between left and right (as though you're looking from the one point towards the next point in the sequence).

I want to take the midpoint of that straight line between two points, shoot 90 degrees off either left or right (let's say `i % 2` or something), travel set distance `d` and place a point at the end location. The distance `d` will be different for each point and I have determined values for each of them.

[image]

Then continue iterating each point while creating offset points at set distances alternating left or right from the reference of the midway line between two points.

[image]

When iterating a point, instead of drawing a straight line from `startX, startY` to `endX, endY`, I will draw 2 lines - one from `startX, startY` to `diversionX, diversionY` and one from that to `endX, endY`. The final rendered result would be this.

[image]

What I'm really asking is for help with the offset dot placing, I didn't have a great relationship with geometry at school, forever this has haunted me.. Drawing paths is trivial, I just need to know the point coordinates where to draw to/from..

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var pointSize = 5;

var points = [
  [300, 50, 10], // x, y, offset point distance
  [175, 80, 15],
  [100, 185, 9],
  [100, 315, 21],
  [175, 420, 12],
  [300, 460, 15],
  [420, 420, 8],
  [500, 315, 16],
  [500, 185, 25],
  [420, 80, 17]
];

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  x = points[i][0];
  y = points[i][1];
  d = points[i][2]; // diversion length
  
  // draw point
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.fillRect(x-(pointSize/2), y-(pointSize/2), pointSize, pointSize);  
  
  // draw temporary connecting line to next point
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#d4d4d4';
  nextPoint = points[(i + 1) % points.length];
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineTo(nextPoint[0], nextPoint[1]);
  ctx.stroke();    
  
  // aaaaand I'm lost
  // get midpoint of drawn line
  // shoot off 90 degress to a side (i %2)
  // travel distance of "d"
  // get "d" x, y position
  
  // draw lines between 
  // x,y and dx,dy
  // dx,dy and nextX, nextY
 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Getting the center point of a line**

```js
mid.X = (start.X + end.X) / 2;
mid.Y = (start.Y + end.Y) / 2;
```

**Getting a vector from two points**

```js
vec.X = end.X - start.X;
vec.Y = end.Y - start.Y;
```

**Getting a vector form point => position**

This is just like having a vector from 0, 0 to the point => your position so:

```js
vec.X = mid.X;
vec.Y = mid.Y;
```

**Turning by 90 degrees**

```js
// Depending on the direction you'd either have to negate the x or y component
const prevY = vec.Y;
vec.Y = vec.X;
vec.X = -prevY;

const prevY = vec.Y;
vec.Y = -vec.X;
vec.X = prevY;
```

**Going a certain distance**

```js
// You have 'point' in your case the center point and the rotated vector 'vec'
// Here you first calculate the length of 'vec'
// then get dX and dY that you move per unit in the direction of 'vec'
// then you multiply that with the distance and get your offset
const vecLength = Math.sqrt(vec.X * vec.X + vec.Y * vec.Y);
const xOffset = vec.X / vecLength * distance;
const yOffset = vec.Y / vecLength * distance;
```

**Add an offset** (but I guess that's not the difficult part ;) )

```js
point.X += xOffset;
point.Y += yOffset;
```

This is the implemented solution: There are a few temporary drawings just to make it a bit clearer what is happening at every step.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pointSize = 5;

const points = [
  [300, 50, 50], // x, y, offset point distance
  [175, 80, 15],
  [100, 185, 9],
  [100, 315, 21],
  [175, 420, 12],
  [300, 460, 15],
  [420, 420, 8],
  [500, 315, 16],
  [500, 185, 25],
  [420, 80, 17]
];

for(let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  x = points[i][0];
  y = points[i][1];
  d = points[i][2]; // diversion length
  
  // draw point
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.fillRect(x-(pointSize/2), y-(pointSize/2), pointSize, pointSize);  
  
  // draw temporary connecting line to next point
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#d4d4d4';
  nextPoint = points[(i + 1) % points.length];
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineTo(nextPoint[0], nextPoint[1]);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  const midX = (x + nextPoint[0]) / 2;
  const midY = (y + nextPoint[1]) / 2;
  
  // draw center point
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
  ctx.fillRect(midX-(pointSize/2), midY-(pointSize/2), pointSize, pointSize); 
  
  const midXVec = nextPoint[0] - midX;
  const midYVec = nextPoint[1] - midY;
  
  const nMidXVec = i % 2 === 0 ? -midYVec : midYVec;
  const nMidYVec = i % 2 === 0 ? midXVec : -midXVec;
  
  // draw rotated vector from midpoint
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#f1f1f1';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(midX, midY);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineTo(midX + nMidXVec, midY + nMidYVec);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  const nMidLength = Math.sqrt(nMidXVec * nMidXVec + nMidYVec * nMidYVec);
  const dXVec = nMidXVec / nMidLength * d;
  const dYvec = nMidYVec / nMidLength * d;
  
  const dX = midX + dXVec;
  const dY = midY + dYvec;
  
  // draw point dX, dY
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.fillRect(dX-(pointSize/2), dY-(pointSize/2), pointSize, pointSize); 
  
  
  // draw final lines
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineTo(dX, dY);
  ctx.lineTo(nextPoint[0], nextPoint[1]);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: I love you <3 thanks so much!! Was just trying to implement your first answer and BAM you did it all for me. Much love!